# Discord is not defined - line 29

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm developing a bot for Discord and it's been showing me an error that I've tried in some ways to solve, but without success. The error happens when I go to the Discord channel and type **-command**.
Where can I be wrong? I have been following a CodeLyon tutorial on developing a Bot for Discord, the tutorial itself is not old, JANUARY 2021, but I believe that Node.JS made some changes like Discord and now the code doesn't work.

**This is my code: main.js**

```
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Collection()

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Pistolito Online');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'command'){
        client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
});

client.login('Token Here');
```

**This my command file - command.js**

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'command',
  description: "Embeds!",
  execute(message, args, Discord){
      const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#304281')
      .setTitle('Rules')
      .setURL('https://youtube.com/tradutorinsano')
      .setDescription('Este é um método para as regras do servidor')
      .setFields(
        {name: 'Regra 1', value: 'Seja legal'},
        {name: 'Regra 2', value: 'Peça uma música'},
        {name: 'Regra 3', value: 'Siga no Youtube'}
      )
      .setImage('https://static.nationalgeographicbrasil.com/files/styles/image_3200/public/photo-ark-european-wildcat2501892.jpg?w=1600&h=900')
      .setFooter('Tenha certeza que você leu as regras do servidor');

      message.channel.send('newEmbed');
  }
}
```

**Error here:**

```
C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\main.js:29
        client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord);
                                                              ^        

ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\main.js:29:63)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:34:18)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\novo\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1098:20)
```

Comment: You have never defined anything called `Discord`, so  `client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord)` fails. You need to import it or create something and assign it to that variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: Discord is not defined; just when trying to kick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613310/referenceerror-discord-is-not-defined-just-when-trying-to-kick)

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: However you have the same issue and the answer provided is the right one, read the documentation about module exportation!

Answer (score 0):

**Try defining discord**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
```

**Or Call it in on exports.execute**

```js
module.exports = {
name: 'command',
description: "Embeds!",
execute(message, args, Discord)
```

[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613310/referenceerror-discord-is-not-defined-just-when-trying-to-kick)